# Typescript union breaking React Higher Order Component type inferrence

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a higher-order component written in Typescript, which is designed to apply the default props to a component. *I'm aware that Typescript 3.0 adds support for `defaultProps`, but I'm not interested in that, since I've come up with another way to type the `defaultProps` already*. I don't use this function anymore, but I'd still like to know why it's broken.

The idea with this HOC is that you can pass in a component type, apply some default props, and end up with another component where the default props you've previously set are now optional.

```
import React from 'react'

/** Type that only contains only keys unique to T */
type LeftOnly<T, U> = { [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]: T[K] }
/** Type that contains keys common to both T and U, and where the values are the same */
type Common<T, U> = { [K in keyof (T | U)]: T[K] extends U[K] ? T[K]: never }

export function withDefaultProps<
    Props,
    DefaultProps extends Partial<Props>,
    FinalProps extends LeftOnly<Props, DefaultProps> & Partial<Common<Props, DefaultProps>>,
    >(component: React.ComponentType<Props>, defaults: DefaultProps) {
    //Return a higher order component that does nothing for now
    return (props: FinalProps) => (<div />)
}

const Person = (props: { name: string, age: number }) => (<div />)
const TestPerson = () => (<Person name="test" age={-999} />) // As expected, requires `name` and `age`

const AgedPerson = withDefaultProps(Person, { age: 999 })
const TestAgedPerson = () => (<AgedPerson name="test" />) // As expected, only `name` is required, while `age` is optional
```

The example above work fine. However, I've found that if I use a union for any of the props, type inference breaks. In the following, I use `'left' | 'right'` as the type for `wheelPosition`, and this causes the HOC (`LeftCar`) to think that ALL props are optional.

```
const Car = (props: { wheelPosition: 'left' | 'right', numWheels: number }) => (<div />)
const TestCar = () => (<Car wheelPosition="left" numWheels={-999} />) // As expected, only left/right can be assigned to `wheelPosition`

const LeftCar = withDefaultProps(Car, { wheelPosition: 'left' })
const TestLeftCar = () => (<LeftCar />) // WHAT? `numWheels` should be required here
```

Interestingly, if the type of `wheelPosition` is changed to `string`, type inference works properly again and the `LeftCar` component now requires `numWheels`.

Why does using a type union cause this to happen?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSB6AKirgBUBPMJOGACxXggDsAbBuGh4wUwbgGc4PfnADWSBpICu3YAEclLGBHpwqFUjCYsAMkkwwA8nwYAeOgBo4AVQB8cALxwA3nADaANJwYnAAogAeaLxKACZItvIMEJj0TonJLq4AugBc9IFZcAC%20lDT0xqwc8ELcImKSiZJCICA8rDoARhDsuijcMS5OfQMA7mxIRJUsAG4o0UiSKJPsLOIoICz6hhUAwrit3PZObp4%20-kEh6SkAFHRwAD4uAJS5%20QGFSOEwSP2SzgVwAD8b1e3CQ0wmxXIn0gsDgmBUGGAbRGwHYABFzCglLwYAAFHBgcS2UhwMlwAkQIkOUnkzGYbG4ylEuCfb6-ClLGDAOa2ZniVw08lwABiYjm-NZXx%20MUkZgs1n4fMJ4ic9MZ%20JV7gAZJzYDzeLY9i0eMqqaq4OqcZrza5BbSya5rs1IGDanlkOgYAA6Y2un4wRjMM1EwVwOIM63iPJWpkqp4%20B1wCgUZAwJRQbhwFBwNjAADm4ygUigcWLLp4AcqnHDEAWcG43Tz3Hz8OgDYgIyTRHTmbg1zAKryYu4Evjnnc11sMWA02TriepBKpBq4ngeIm4jaXgHQ7Oo42eTXUDE%20aG%20aQeW4ShAHUhRQTHkn09n88Xq-gdAW%20M32-7j%20fDcoC3LMDyQDwACJvjXCDswvDxvAAWgATlQoo32TCg4AAQUkGEkAwJAYicIgNGAIhJAAAzAyjs36OBKJQC9KPID8cIvGIgJA05UQxLFrX5a4uJ4JxfCYy84FQ5DinfHg13ob9sI44Ssx3AD%201sJSiJUht1nAqDv1gigF0wnC8PCZhCOIqQbAYmjgkkUilHIoinDGYBeBYRjmIcqQwG5Hg5lYuT4B2JZTl3c08l8MYkCQXg8QgcQ0WRbg8nwTyLHwB4CBPQsYHwJxrxAAB1cZ4ujBsbzvYsHwnDSZznYzZIkT9vzC4s1PqqcOrgWL4sS5KAu4SDMpgWDirKuLeHEBCULQjCUzMqVLO%20azpAEMaKDythqj6OA72zcRkvzMEBm0Bj%20oSpKUp4FiVxCuB5RgXqvF4thYxtIlrg60S%20vK66htS9Kxuyh8HtahS12e17-262wYfC5rTJKgAJbC6GBaibymiraPENgIBxAZDqclyBiLJAgA)

Comment: There is an issue with your Common type usage. See: `type Y = Common<{ wheelPosition: "left" | "right", numWheels: number }, { wheelPosition: "left"}>;` gets inferred towards `never`. If you swap how ever both types around: `type Y = Common<{ wheelPosition: "left"}, { wheelPosition: "left" | "right", numWheels: number }>;` it get's correctly inferred. That's because the union type "left" | "right" extends "left" and not the other way around ("left" does not extend "left"|"right").

Comment: I'm currently looking at getting rid of those `LeftOnly` and `Common` types, and am trying to recreate the logic using the in-built `Omit` type instead. Thanks for the pointer about the order of the types, it'll help me as I change my code